# iOS - trigger event on Proximity using iBeacons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon

I am working on an iOS app using the new iOS7 API : iBeacon.

I am simply trying to trigger an event when I detect a given proximity, Immediate here (out of the 4, the others are Near, Far and Unknown).

When I build up my app on my iPhone 4S, it works. So I could say I'm done, but since I am very new to iOS, I am not sure at all if my implementation is in anyway *correct* or, even worse if it's not the case, *safe*.

I basically implemented my event in my view controller (objective-c class) and call it in the *locationManager* method where the beacons get ranged. I took the code given in the sample app [AirLocate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013430), if you want to see how it goes.

My event is simply calling another view (in order to give access to some new features on that particular view, only when you're in immediate proximity with my Beacon). I thought of this being *smart* because every time my beacons get ranged, an if condition runs too and if it is true, my event gets called.

Below is my if condition which is at the end of the *locationManager* method :

```
    //Beacons ranging method from Apple until here.
    //My code following the sample code.

    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];
    if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) {
        [self immediateDetection];
    }
    //End of the method here, which would be closed by the last "}"
```

And here is my little method/event :

```
    - (void)immediateDetection
    {
        NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HueSwitch"];

        //call another view
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

As I said, it works fine on my iPhone but I have no way to know if it is a no go as it is.

**So, am I just being silly and it seems to be all fine or does my code have some serious security or stability issues?**

Thank you.

Comment: the only one suggestion: ranging produces very frequently delegate calls, sou you need check that "immediate" view already on screen and not present it again

Comment: `CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];` -- this line not needed

Comment: Ok, is the following correct? instead of the 2 first code lines, I would have only that one :
`CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons lastObject];`

Comment: yea, please see my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little rewrite of your code

```
CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons lastObject];
if (beacon && beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) {
   [self immediateDetection];
}
```

and in second part, add check to not present view if it already visible

```
 - (void)immediateDetection
{
    if (self.presentedViewController)
    {
      return;
    }
    // rest of code here
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your very fast answer. Now that you pointed it out, it seems basic logic, to check if the view controller is already presented. I am going to test that out first!

Comment: I just thought of this : since I stop the ranging of my beacons when my view did disappears. Is your test really necessary? Because if there is no ranging, there is no test if my device is in immediate proximity of my beacon, and therefore my view controller can't get called "again" anyway. Does it sound right or am I heading in the wrong way with my assumption?

Comment: If you are sure, it will be ok, I just worry about async nature of iBeacon and UI.